# Visual Studio 2010 Lazily Quantified Regex Replace

Tags: regex, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Is there a way to do a non-greedy Regex replace / Regex find in VS 2010?

I mean for the find-and-replace feature in visual studio: NOT a regex.replace method.

I'm doing something like this to remove terrible exception handling:

```
Find: Catch <.*> As Exception(.*\n)*.*End Try
```

but because the `(.*\n)*` is greedy, it won't behave like I want it to (and it takes forever).

Here's an example of something that doesn't match correctly:

```
Try
    'blah blah blah
Catch ex As Exception
End Try
Try
    'blah blah blah
Catch ex As Exception
End Try
```

Comment: Could you please provide sample input? Right now, it matches a simple `Catch <text> As Exception Text
            Text
            Text End Try`

Comment: Yep! Now try putting your string into something that's 2000 lines long, and see how long it takes.

Comment: Have you tried making it lazy using a `?`?

Comment: @Matthew as far as I can tell that doesn't work with default VS functionality. I'm hoping there's a plug in or something that I can use to expand the regex functionality... I just can't find anything.

Comment: Works for me in vs2012.  What is your regex when doing lazy capture?

Comment: @Matthew `Catch <.*> As Exception(.*\n)*?.*End Try`. I'm using VS 2010

Comment: Can you add the sample code you're looking to replace?  (including before and after)

Comment: @Matthew it's an entire solution with hundreds of thousands of lines of code. This is part of a refactoring to remove terrible error handling that essentially went `try ... catch ex As Exception : throw new Exception()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes: use an at sign (`@`).

In VS 2010:

```
ab@c
```

Is equivalent to:

```
ab*?c
```

It was pretty lame, but they've fortunately changed it all in newer versions of Visual Studio.

In your example, it would be this:

```
Find: Catch <.@> As Exception(.@\n)@.@End Try
```

Documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx).

Comment: Awesome! Got through the all of it in just ten seconds.